# .NET Core CLR spends half its time waiting on ntdll.dll

Tags: c#, .net, performance, profiling

I am profiling a highly parallel project with dotTrace and noticed that the CLR is spending almost 50% of its time waiting for `ntdll.dll`. I am having a hard time figuring out what to attribute this to.

[image: dotTrace Timeline]

**Is there a way I can determine what is causing the CLR to spend so much time with calls to the kernel?** I have developed this project to be as low-allocation as possible, and garbage collection usage is negligible compared to the time spent running. The only thing I can think of attributing this to is memory latency or CPU cache misses, as some of the CPU-intensive calculations utilize random memory accesses.

Comment: Which version of .NET Core and which kind of application are you using? Also, have you tried to enable and check ETW to see what happens?

Comment: Enable `Native Code Debugging` and see if you get some native exceptions. Exception handling is expensive. Also, check if you have some thread-locking issues.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution to this problem?